# Haskell: Not in scope: data constructor

Tags: haskell

Started to learn haskell today for school and I run into a problem with function. I don't understand why it's not in the scope..

Heres the code:

```
ff :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]] -> [Char]
ff A B = [[x !! 0, y !! 1] | x <- A, y <- B, (x !! 1) == (y !! 0)]
```

And errors:

```
md31.hs:2:4: Not in scope: data constructor `A'

md31.hs:2:6: Not in scope: data constructor `B'

md31.hs:2:38: Not in scope: data constructor `A'

md31.hs:2:46: Not in scope: data constructor `B'
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As noted in the answers the variable names need to be lowercase.  The official documentation related to this is at http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/intro.html#namespaces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function parameters have to start with a lowercase letter in Haskell.

As such, you'd need to make `A` and `B` lowercase (`a` and `b`) in your function definition.

If the first letter of an identifier is in uppercase, it is assumed to be a [data constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor).

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell the capital letters mean that value is data constructor as in:

```
data Test = A | B
```

If you need variable use lowercase:

```
ff a b = [[x !! 0, y !! 1] | x <- a, y <- b, (x !! 1) == (y !! 0)]
```