# Why I am forced to write the (Data Constructor) name with first letter in small case?

Tags: haskell

Why I am forced to write `liOfLi` in place of `LiOfLi`? Please guide.

code in baby.hs

> LiOfLi = [ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20],  [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]

ghci response:

> ghci> :l baby
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )
>   Failed, modules loaded: none.
>
> ghci> 
>   baby.hs:29:1: Not in scope: data constructor `LiOfLi'

When changing the initial letter to smaller case

code in baby.hs

> liOfLi = [ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20],  [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]

ghci response:

> ghci> :l baby
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )
>   Ok, modules loaded: Main.

Following are the SO questions I referred but I failed to understand the rules/ logic and get the answer for (my) abovementioned question.

[Why does Haskell force data constructor's first letter to be upper case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237775/why-does-haskell-force-data-constructors-first-letter-to-be-upper-case)

the variable names need to be lowercase. The official documentation related to this is at [haskell.org/onlinereport/intro.html#namespaces](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/intro.html#namespaces) –  (the SO comment by)  [Chris Kuklewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010850/haskell-not-in-scope-data-constructor#comment9803452_8010850)

Comment: `liOfLi` is not a data constructor. It is a variable.

Comment: in haskell you often go by making the the quasi plural by appending an 's' (or sometimes i use the same letter twice), i.e. if I got a list of integers `i`, one would write `is` or `ii` for a list of integers - I would then repeat the same `iss` or `iii`. There is usually another name that comes to use for a list of lists of numbers -- matrix. but `liOfLi` is hard to read and always reminds me of the german lullaby http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TS-W5woDcw ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data constructors (type constructors also) must begin with an uppercase letter. In your second example that actually compiles, `liOfLi` is not a data constructor, it's a variable (which begin with lower-case letters).

This:

```
liOfLi = [ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20], [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]
```

declares that a variable `liOfLi` is equal to `[ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20], [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]`.

On the other hand, this:

```
LiOfLi = [ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20], [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]
```

is a pattern match of the pattern `LiOfLi` against the expression `[ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20], [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]`. As a pattern match it's fairly useless, because it contains no variables so even if it worked it wouldn't do anything. It fails to compile `LiOfLi` as a pattern is looking for all expressions matching the constructor `LiOfLi` applied to 0 arguments; since the constructor `LiOfLi` isn't defined anywhere your program can't be compiled.

The only way you could make `LiOfLi` be a 0-argument constructor is to introduce a new type, like so:

```
data MyNewType = LiOfLi
```

But `LiOfLi = [ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20], [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]` still wouldn't work, because it's trying to match the pattern `LiOfLi`, which is a pattern for values of type `MyNewType`, against the value `[ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20], [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]`, which is a value of the list type.

Basically that equation means two different things depending on whether the term on the left of the `=` is interpreted as a pattern or as a variable. Haskell's designers chose to make it always easy to tell (for both human readers and the compiler) whether a given identifier is a constructor or a variable by the case of its first letter, which in turn allows you tell whether an equation is a pattern binding or a variable definition.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
liOfLi = [ [1,3,4,5,6,8], [ 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20], [23, 24, 25, 45, 56] ]
```

you define the **variable** `liOfLi` to yield the value given by the list of lists.
In contrast, a [Data Constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Data_constructor) is used to define an algebraic data type, for example, you could define the following data type:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Here, `Nil` and `Node` are both data constructors for type `Tree a`. You can look at their types in ghci, which will show:

```
Node :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
Nil  :: Tree a
```

Comment: `liOfLi` isn't a function, it's a variable with type `[Integer]`.  If it were a function, it would be a variable with a type of the form `α -> β`.  (See ["'Everything is a function' in Haskell?"](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell) for a discussion of why everything is *not* a function.)

Comment: Ok, although I somewhat disagree with calling it a "variable", as its value is fixed.

Comment: See the question ["Does Haskell Have Variables?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993124/does-haskell-have-variables) for a discussion of that exact question :-)  The stance I take is that it's a variable in the math sense, as well as the term used in the Haskell Report.

Answer (score 1):

A "data constructor" in Haskell is connected to a custom type. It gives data a certain context, it isn't actually the data. Types and data constructors must be uppercase.

Lowercase indicates a name for a function or a variable. When you use that lowercase name in your example, it could be replaced by the list on the right side.

In this case, the data constructor is `[]` (actually shorthand for something else).

Comment: `liOfLi` isn't a function, it's a variable with type `[Integer]`.  If it were a function, it would be a variable with a type of the form `α -> β`.  (See ["'Everything is a function' in Haskell?"](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell) for a discussion of why everything is *not* a function.)  Similarly, data constructors aren't types, they are values.  `Maybe` has two constructors, `Just` and `Nothing`.

Comment: In this case I would fall under the category of keeping things simple. It seemed like the asker had the wrong idea, thus trying to make it clear that capital letters are type-related, and lowercase indicates that you can replace the left side of the equal-sign with the right side (this is my mnemonic from math for functions.) But I'll edit to be more precise.

Comment: Definitely laudable motivation!  It's just that I've seen a number of people get confused by the difference between data types and data constructors; for instance, saying things like "so this has type cons here".